# Capture username to write in new post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, closures

When a user signs in, their UID is set to standardUserDefaults(). Also, the users' profile data is saved under a child named their uid.

When the user creates a post, I would like to attach their username/display name to the post.

I've set up a function to fetch the current user's username, but whenever I submit a post, it seems as though the closure is not being executed.

The post model:

```
class PostModel {
    var postBody = String()
    var creationDate = String()
    var postUID = String()
    var userName = String()

    init(postBody: String) {
        self.postBody = postBody
        let dateObject = NSDate()
        let formatDate = timeToString(dateObject)
        self.creationDate = formatDate
        let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String
        self.postUID = userID
        self.userName = getUsername(userID)
    }

    // Used to convert the model to json compatible before saving
    func postToDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
        let jsonBody = postBody
        let jsonDate = creationDate
        let jsonUID = postUID
        let jsonUsername = userName
        let postAsDictionary = ["Body": jsonBody, "Timestamp": jsonDate, "UID": jsonUID, "Display Name": jsonUsername]
        return postAsDictionary
    }
}
```

and the function to get the username:

```
func getUsername(withUID: String) -> String {
    var userName = String()
    DataService.ref.userRef.childByAppendingPath(withUID).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        userName = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Display Name") as! String
    })
    return userName
}
```

Comment: That's not how Firebase works. It's asynchonous in nature so you would most likely be returning a nil value as the code will execute before the block completes. With firebase, you should only go to the next 'step' once you know the block has completed. Firebase should not be used as a synchronous function call to return a value.

Comment: Okay, thank you. What would you suggest? Should i have the user log in and as soon as the first screen loads, set their username to standardUserDefaults() or take an entirely different route?

Comment: A possible flow is: present login screen. User enteres username and password. Authenticate through firebase - if successful (within the Auth block) write to user defaults (not sure why you would need to do that) and proceed to the next app screen. The user uid is always available from the Firebase authData variable so when the user creates a post, obtain the uid from there. If you need other data for the user, like their name, you obtain that once they auth. So the sequence is auth->get uid->load user data from user node->proceed with app

Answer (score 0):

I set up my login function to get the current user's display name and set it to the standardUserDefaults which worked. I believe this is my solution unless someone has a better suggestion

```
    @IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
      if emailField != nil && passwordField != nil {

        let emailAttempt = emailField.text!
        let passwordAttempt = passwordField.text!
        DataService.ref.baseRef.authUser(emailAttempt, password: passwordAttempt) {
            error, authData in
            if error != nil {
                print("error in data check")
            } else {
                let returnUID = authData.uid
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(returnUID , forKey: "uid")
                DataService.ref.userRef.childByAppendingPath(returnUID).childByAppendingPath("Display Name").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                    let UserDisplayName = snapshot.value as! String
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(UserDisplayName, forKey: "displayName")
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccessSegue", sender: sender)

                })

            }
        }
      } else {
        print("error")
        return
      } 
   }
```

Comment: While this will work, it's not an answer to the question 'Capture username to write in new post'; this code writes data to the user defaults. What it also means is that every time the user creates a post, you'll have to read from user defaults. Also, what if the user is a person that get's married and changes their last name, or the person decides to go by Frank instead of Franklin? That means every post will have the wrong name stored within it. There's also a dangling return in your else statement. In general, you should update your question instead of answering your own question.